# No play.test.FunctionalTest in play 2.0 how to write functional test?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am newbie in Java & play framework. Currently I'm using Play framework 2.0 and there are no class play.test.FunctionalTest. How to write functiona test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the examples in your sample applications.

One of the ready-provided examples is at ${PLAY_FRAMEWORK}/samples/java/computer-database/test/FunctionalTest.java, quoting below:

```
import org.junit.*;

import java.util.*;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.test.*;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.test.Helpers.*;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;

public class FunctionalTest {

    @Test
    public void redirectHomePage() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.index());

               assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(SEE_OTHER);
               assertThat(redirectLocation(result)).isEqualTo("/computers");
           }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void listComputersOnTheFirstPage() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.list(0, "name", "asc", ""));

               assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
               assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("574 computers found");
           }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void filterComputerByName() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.list(0, "name", "asc", "Apple"));

               assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
               assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("13 computers found");
           }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void createANewComputer() {
        running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.save());

                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(BAD_REQUEST);

                Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put("name", "FooBar");
                data.put("introduced", "badbadbad");
                data.put("company.id", "1");

                result = callAction(
                    controllers.routes.ref.Application.save(), 
                    fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(data)
                );

                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(BAD_REQUEST);
                assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("<option value=\"1\" selected>Apple Inc.</option>");
                assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("<input type=\"text\" id=\"introduced\" name=\"introduced\" value=\"badbadbad\" >");
                assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("<input type=\"text\" id=\"name\" name=\"name\" value=\"FooBar\" >");

                data.put("introduced", "2011-12-24");

                result = callAction(
                    controllers.routes.ref.Application.save(), 
                    fakeRequest().withFormUrlEncodedBody(data)
                );

                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(SEE_OTHER);
                assertThat(redirectLocation(result)).isEqualTo("/computers");
                assertThat(flash(result).get("success")).isEqualTo("Computer FooBar has been created");

                result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.list(0, "name", "asc", "FooBar"));
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
                assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("One computer found");

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

play.test.FunctionalTest does not exist.

How to write a functiona test should read the document here.

- https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/JavaTest

## Testing your application

Test source files must be placed in your application’s `test` folder. You can run tests from the Play console using the `test` and `test-only` tasks.

### Using JUnit

The default way to test a Play 2 application is with [[JUnit| http://www.junit.org/]].

```
package test;

import org.junit.*;

import play.mvc.*;
import play.test.*;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.test.Helpers.*;
import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.*;

public class SimpleTest {

```
@Test 
public void simpleCheck() {
    int a = 1 + 1;
    assertThat(a).isEqualTo(2);
}
```

}
```